# Remove a substring from a string starting from a character

Tags: java, string, substring

> Narrator: Kids, if you are single is all this happy ever after.
>   [Title: the year of 2030]. But only one of your stories can end that
>   way. The rest end with someone getting hurt. This is one of those
>   stories, and it starts… with a shirt.

From the string above, how will I remove the sentence surrounded by []. Thus, this

> [Title: the year of 2030].

will be taken out. The string then becomes

Narrator: Kids, when you’re single all you’re looking for is happily ever after. But only one of your stories can end that way. The rest end with someone getting hurt. This is one of those stories, and it starts… with a shirt.

Comment: So you want to extract that part or remove it from the main String?

Comment: remove it from the main string

Comment: The replaceAll solutions are great, or simply use the good ol' indexof / substring method

Comment: BTW is it from HIMYM? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Narrator: Kids, if you are single is all this happy ever after. [Title: the year of 2030]. But only one of your stories can end that way. The rest end with someone getting hurt. This is one of those stories, and it starts… with a shirt.";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", ""));
}
```

O/P :

> Narrator: Kids, if you are single is all this happy ever after. . But
>   only one of your stories can end that way. The rest end with someone
>   getting hurt. This is one of those stories, and it starts… with a
>   shirt.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression with [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), but you need to escape the `[` and `]` characters (because they have special meaning in a regex). Something like,

```
String story = "Narrator: Kids, if you are single is all this happy "
    + "ever after. [Title: the year of 2030]. But only one of your stories "
    + "can end that way. The rest end with someone getting hurt. "
    + "This is one of those stories, and it starts… with a shirt.";
story = story.replaceAll("\\[.*\\]", "");
System.out.println(story);
```

Comment: `\\[.*\\]` if there are 2 of them, it will remove everything in between as well :P

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this.

```
String str = "Narrator: Kids,if you are single is all this happy ever after. [Title: the year of 2030]. But (...)";
    StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder(str);

      int start = str.indexOf("[");
      int end = str.indexOf("]")+1;
    strBuild.delete(start, end);
    System.out.println(strBuild);
```